# How to access describe and it messages in mocha?

Tags: mocha.js

In mocha,

```
describe('this message text', function(){
    it('and this message text', function(done){
        console.log(this); // {} is empty
    });
});
```

How to access `'this message text'` `'and this message text'` from inside the tests?

I tried `this` object but it's empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.test.parent.title;`

Ctx for a suite has a test object which represents the currently executing test which has a parent to the suite (describe) above it.

You can also access the title of the current test by `this.test.title` etc.

This method allows getting the data (and other data) you are looking for without having to grab it in the `before()` etc functions.

Answer (score 5):

As you discovered, accessing `this` inside the callback for `it` does not work. Here's one way to do it:

```
describe('this message text', function () {
    var suite_name = this.title;
    var test_name;

    beforeEach(function () {
        test_name = this.currentTest.title;
    });

    it('and this message text', function () {
        console.log(suite_name, test_name);
    });

    it('and this other message text', function () {
        console.log(suite_name, test_name);
    });
});
```

The workaround in the code above is that the `beforeEach` hook grabs the test name before the test is run and saves it in `test_name`.

If you wonder what the value of `this` is inside a test callback, it is the value of the `ctx` field on the suite to which the test belongs. For instance, the `console.log` statement in this:

```
describe('suite', function () {
    this.ctx.foo = 1;

    it('test', function () {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

would output:

```
{
  "foo": 1
}
```

Comment: Be aware not to use arrow function, cause it does not bind `this` to the function.